# "I am" or "I was"?

Tags: life-of-jesus, gospel-of-john

*"I tell you the truth," Jesus answered, "before Abraham was born, I am!"*

*John 8:58 (NIV)*

Is this a grammatical error? Or is it because the Trinity does not experience time as we do, and are (is) everywhere; past, present, future?

Comment: A combination of the later (because God was, is, and will be), and also because "I Am" is the name God gave when Moses asked Him for identification. Jesus was being very deliberate (as evidenced by the crowd's reaction) in identifying *Himself* with the same name as the Jewish God. (Because both the Father and the Son *are* God.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Moses asked "who he should say sent him?" when he first met God in the Burning Bush on Mount Horeb in the beginning of Exodus, this is who God Himself said Moses says he should say sent him.

> "I AM sent me" - Exodus 3:14

Later, in the John's Revelation, John uses the opposite terminology to describe the beast at the end of the world:

> The beast that you saw—it was, and now is no more, but is about to come up out of the Abyss and go to its destruction. And those who dwell on the earth whose names were not written in the Book of Life from the foundation of the world will marvel when they see the beast that was, and is not, and yet will be.

> Rev 17:8 - https://biblehub.com/revelation/

This moment in John's Gospel is one of the key turning points where Jesus really reveals Himself as God. So it's important to consider that.  It's not about grammar , or understanding the Trinity, as much as it's about a clear understanding of who Jesus is and why He's about to get stoned in the next sentence.

Comment: Then "I am" Jesus's statement is one of the names of God? I mean, it would make no sense to me if you said, "I tell you the truth, before this happened, Peter Turner". 

So it is not a grammatical error, and neither is it an analogy to the the Trinity being every where, but a proper noun?

Comment: yep, that would be pretty jarring.  If it were just a grammatical error  then you'd have to assume that all the people who picked up rocks to stone Him were overzealous English teachers.

Comment: @JohnCarter, the name "I Am" is also a declaration; to wit, God declares Himself as a **brute fact** (that is, uncaused). In a sense, Jesus is saying, "before Abraham was, I exist". The alteration of tense here isn't an error, but deliberate, to emphasize that said existence isn't merely in the past, but eternal and not bound to time. And "I Am" *also* serves as a proper noun. That the words work on both levels is almost certainly deliberate.

Comment: @Matthew good point, I didn't mean to say by my answer that John Carter was wrong in interpreting it that way - it's just that the words can mean something else too.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thanks PeterTurner and @Matthew.

Comment: Right. It's both, and the "proper noun" interpretation is important for understanding how the Jews reacted. The alternate meaning is why it's *quirky* (and also deliberate) grammar as opposed to grammatical nonsense, the way "before this happened, Peter Turner" is grammatical nonsense. 

Answer (score -2):

The Greek translates the "I AM" in Exodus 3:14 as `ego eimi`, **same as John 8:58**.

This means that Jesus reiterated what he said as the Angel of God in the Burning Bush.

Now, contrary to Trinitarian thought, Jesus' remark of "Before Abraham was, I AM" was not a declaration of himself being God, but instead a declaration that he was the only begotten Son of God who has God's Spirit indwelled inside of him fully, and who God has given his Holy Name, to manifest the fullness of His essence bodily in the presence of man.

The Spirit of God that abided in him was carrying out God's will on earth to work out the salvation of the chosen ones unto adoption as sons of God.

For Jesus said, "Holy Father, keep them in Your Name, the Name which you have given me, so that they may be one with you as I am one with you." (John 17:11)

Jesus Christ, the Chief Angel of God, is the viceroy of God's Presence on earth. (John 1:18)

Comment: Please take the time to carefully proof read your posts, so that you don't need to make 27 edits in the space of an hour or two.

Comment: The question mentions the Trinity, so answers should ordinarily assume Trinitarian thought. To Trinitarian, your answer seems like little more than avoiding acknowledging the Trinity since you assert I AM doesn't mean Christ is God but that he's the Son of God but omits how that sentence is actually fitting for someone who is not God to say (indwelling Spirit, "fullness of essence bodily in the presence of man" notwithstanding) nor why the Jews clearly did understand it as a claim to divinity.

Comment: @menorahman. So just for clarification are you saying Jesus is an actual angel? And if he is, is his name Michael the arc angel? Also, it says at Exodus 3:2, "And the angel of the Lord appeared to him in a blazing fire from the midst of the bush; and he looked and behold, the bush was burning with fire, yet the bush was not consumed. Mose turned aside etc. Vs4, The Lord saw that he turned aside to look, God called to him from the midst of the bush. At vs6, God said, I am the God of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob. So, who called from the midst of the bush? Was it an angel or was it God Almighty?

Comment: @Mr.Bond Yes, Jesus is actually an angel. The Chief Angel, to be exact. He is God's special only-begotten Son, who is the commander of all God's forces of lesser angelic "sons of God". The Son of God commands the sons of God, the Army of Light. And yes, Jesus' angelic name is "Michael", which means "He who is like God". Who called from the midst of the bush? It was the Angel of the Presence, Michael, the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ, who is the supreme viceroy of God and the Intercessor. God the Father was speaking through his Interceding Son, the Chief Angel of God on behalf of God.

Comment: Calm your spirit, @eques. Yes, I am rejecting the Triune Godhead doctrine, because it is completely unbiblical and frankly blasphemous. Jesus never stated that he was God in the flesh, neither did he declare any form of Deity. But he did declare himself to be like God, which is the meaning of the name "Michael". That is because Jesus is the Son of God, the Chief Angel or "archangel", the Commander of the sons of God (lesser angels) in heaven. When Jesus states "I AM", he is declaring himself to be the revelation of the Son of God as the sole Intercessor between God and man.

Comment: @menorahman You are new here, so you may not get how this works. This is not a debate site and denominational debating is off-limits in questions/answers (chat is a separate case). So my comment is on the spot. You are free to ask questions and answer according to non-trinitarian theology (it happens quite readily) but you are not free to co-opt questions about Trinitarian theology to suit your own theology (although plenty of non-trinitarians do that).

Comment: @menorahman The rest of your comment is the repeating the same claims of your answer, which a) won't convince Trinitarians (non-trinitarians seem very surprised that Trinitarians actually do use the Bible to derive their theology). You may say Jesus is Michael (JWs?) but again, that's based upon a theological connection that other groups do not recognize and so will not accept. It's also far more tenuous that saying I AM in John 8 implies

Comment: No worries friend, I am not JW. On the contrary, Trinitarians are surprised to find that Paulician Unitarians such as myself are eager to acknowledge and magnify the term "I AM" applied to Jesus Christ, but that the declaration of this term is not a claim to Deity, but a claim to being God's Royal Intercessor, the Heavenly Viceroy of God's Presence on earth. This is because Jesus Christ (Chief Angel 'Michael') is the only-begotten Son of God among the lesser sons of God, and the visible face of the invisible God, heaven-sent, for mankind on earth to prepare for adoption as sons of God.

Comment: @menorahman If the angel of the Lord is Michael, who is an actual angel answer me this? It says at Genesis 22:11 where the AOTL calls from heaven 2 times, here and at vs11 and at vs15. He says at vs16, "and said, "By Myself I have sworn declares the Lord, because you have done this thing and have not withheld your son, your only son, vs17, indeed I will greatly bless you and I will greatly multiply your seed as the stars of the heavens and as the sand which is on the seashore. At vs18, the earth will be blessed because you obeyed My voice. Question? Can an angel swear an oath on behalf of God?

Comment: @Mr.Bond Yes, an angel can swear an oath on behalf of God as long as the angel has been given God's Name YHWH. which grants him the authority that comes with it. Only the Son of God can swear an oath on behalf of God his Father, for he has been given Holy Name as the only begotten who is the firstborn of creation to be the Redeemer of the future sons of God, to the glorification of spiritual Israel.

Comment: @menorahman An angel, or even a man cannot swear an oath on behalf of another, especially for God Himself. If you were to read Hebrews 6:13-18 you would never assume that an angel is swearing an oath for God. "For when God made the promise to Abraham, since He could swear by no one greater, HE SWORE BY HIMSELF," saying, "I will surely bless you, and I will surely multiply you." This is referring back to Genesis 22. The following deals with "His name is in him." https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/41981/what-does-my-name-is-with-him-mean-in-exodus-2321 Continued!

Comment: Cont. Also, Jesus cannot be both Michael the arc angel and the Messiah. Your making a category error by comparing title to ontological beings.  The angel of the Lord is the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ. The Hebrew word for angel is "malak" and it simply means "messenger." It's true that angels are messengers and so are men. Please read Malachi 3:1. The first angel/messenger is John the Baptist, a man. The second angel/messenger of the covenant in whom you delight, behold, He is coming, says the Lord of hosts. This would be Jesus Christ. Since Jesus is TAOTL/God it makes sense He swore the oath.

Comment: @Mr.Bond Matthew 5:34-37 Jesus said, "But I tell you **do not swear at all**: either by heaven, for it is God’s throne; or by the earth, for it is His footstool; or by Jerusalem, for it is the city of the great King. Nor should you swear by your head, for you cannot make a single hair white or black. Simply let your ‘Yes’ be ‘Yes,’ and your ‘No,’ ‘No.’ Anything more comes from the evil one." Because Jesus wields the supreme authority of God's Name given to him, he has the authority to swear upon himself, just as God. Both the Father and the Son share the throne, and soon so shall we.

Comment: @menorahman No, Jesus commanded His followers not to make an oath of any kind, because a disciple must be dependable enough that his word alone is adequate, vs37. Swearing by heaven or earth is actually swearing by God, vs33, for the heavens are God's throne and the earth His footstool. At Matthew 26:63 (the trial of Jesus) the high priest said to Jesus, "I adjure/swear You by the living God, that You tell us whether (1) are you the Christ, and (2) the Son of God." At Luke 22:70 Jesus said, "Yes, I am." Saying your the exclusive Son of God is claiming to be God. He was accused of blasphemy.

Comment: @menorahman we are only surprised because it is poorly explained and to use your term, unbiblical.